# Java Threads in Netbeans - throw new UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I am trying to implement Round Robin using Threads in Java and facing this problem.
When i run this program it asks me for process id and time quantum for the process to run but after i specify it just displays a message BUILD SUCCESSFUL and doesn't show the round Robin process preemption. However if i use cmd and execute the same code it works fine please Help....???

```
package thread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class job implements Runnable {
int process_id,no_of_instr,time_quantum;
Thread t;
public job(int pid,int instr,int tq) {
    process_id=pid;
    no_of_instr=instr;
    time_quantum=tq;
    t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
    System.out.println("Process Id " + process_id); 
    for(int i=0;i<no_of_instr;i++) {
        System.out.println("Executing Instruction no " + i + " for Process      id " + process_id);
        Thread.sleep(time_quantum);
        }

    System.out.println("Job " + process_id + " is over");

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);
            } // end of catch
    } // end of run
```

}

```
public class Thread {

static void sleep(int time_quantum) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To   change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

Thread(job aThis) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

void start() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter Process Id");
        int process_id=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Time Quantum (In milliseconds)");
        int time_quantum=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        job j1=new job(++process_id,24,time_quantum);
        job j2=new job(++process_id,3,time_quantum);
        job j3=new job(++process_id,3,time_quantum);
    }catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't create because of Exception" + e);
            }
}
```

}

Comment: Naming your class `Thread` is not a good idea: it's hiding the `java.lang.Thread` class...

Comment: ou should read about java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have gotten the wrong idea about how Java threads work.

The standard threading behavior in Java is implemented by a standard class called `java.lang.Thread`.  This class and the associated JVM infrastructure are what will (would) cause your code to run on different cores.

What you have done is create your own class called `thread.Thread` that has some method signatures that look like a some of the methods in the standard `Thread` API.  But you appear to have implemented those methods with empty bodies.  So, naturally, when your `main()` method calls them, they do absolutely nothing.

This is completely the wrong approach.  You should not be writing your own `thread.Thread` class.  You should be<sup>1</sup> using `java.lang.Thread`.

I recommend that you read the Oracle Java Tutorial's [Concurrency lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), starting from the beginning.

---

<sup>1 - In fact, it is impossible to do what the `java.lang.Thread` class does in pure Java ... unless you go to the extent of implementing your own JVM in Java.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! the java.lang.thread method worked....Actually I am a beginner with java threads and I'll surely check the oracle docs :)